# CSS margin: 0 auto; not working in Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, cross-browser

So I'm developing a fairly basic WordPress site for work. It's all gone relatively well for starters, however upon trying to make my site look the same on multiple browsers I came across an issue.

It would seem that any time I used margin: 0 auto; in my CSS that it simply doesn't apply in Safari. At first I had to add display:-webkit-flex; to get this working so that was one problem out of the way...

However now my divs aren't aligning correctly because Safari seems to ignore my rules I set for margin.

Can anyone please assist me on this matter?

I've attached some screenshots so you can see the difference. I'd attach code but it's literally only in Safari. IE and Mozilla both look the same as intended in Chrome.

Google Chrome Screenshot:
[image: Google Chrome Screenshot]

Safari Screenshot:
[image: Safari Screenshot]

Thanks in advance for viewing this post and potentially solving my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that row is using display flex you shouldn't need margin, as flex defaults to a row then justify-content applies across the row.

That way you can set justify-content to be space-between

[justify-content](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can ensure the content never touches when going responsive via padding on each "item" class justify-content: space-between; will still resolve your spacing issues.

To get comfortable with flex and know all the ins and outs have a look at [FlexFroggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) and [flex cheat sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)